Quarkus. Exception on handshake when using Websockets Next
I've encountered the following exception, when trying to connect to a websocket server using Quarkus Websockets Next client. From exception message and source code I see that exception is raised when handshake response status is not 101. What is the designated the way to catch this exception (I'd like to show it to user with custom message)?
General problem that it's called outside the main thread, so it could not be catch in straightforward way.
2024-10-25 10:32:35,280 ERROR [io.qua.ver.cor.run.VertxCoreRecorder] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) Uncaught exception received by Vert.x: io.vertx.core.http.UpgradeRejectedException: WebSocket upgrade failure: 400
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.WebSocketHandshakeInboundHandler.handshakeComplete(WebSocketHandshakeInboundHandler.java:102)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.WebSocketHandshakeInboundHandler.channelRead(WebSocketHandshakeInboundHandler.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1473)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1336)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1385)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:530)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:469)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1407)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:918)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Update:
I'm using WebSocketConnector.
Quarkus version 3.15.1.
@Inject
WebSocketConnector<ExampleWebsocketClient> connector;
...
public Connection openConnection() {
     var connection = connector.baseUri("ws://example.com")
                    .connectAndAwait();
            //connection is acquired without exceptions
            return connection;
        } catch (CompletionException ex) {
            //never executed
            return null;
        }
}


we will need more information. Do you use WebSocketConnector or BasicWebSocketConnector? What version of Quarkus do you use? In general, the connector should receive the error (either wrapped in a CompletionException for connectAndAwait() or returns a failed Uni for connect()).

Updated the question. connectAndAwait doesn't throw Exception, it's thrown in another thread.
I was able to catch this exception with following code, but it's the preferred result would be if connectAndAwait would throw this exception:
@Inject
io.vertx.core.Vertx vertx;
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
vertx.exceptionHandler(throwable -> {
//do something
});
}

Have you tried to catch the UpgradeRejectedException instead of CompletionException? I believe that CompletionException is only used for checked exceptions.

I've added a test for this specific use case: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/44236
